# Using curl to POST and update multiple data

Tags: python, curl, post, flask, put

I've seen this question asked a lot but the questions have to do with using txt files or data from forms.
I can use curl to POST data when using a json file but I want to know how I can do it by manually adding data into the curl statement. I also tried using PUT in curl statement but couldn't get it to work as well. I looked at a lot of questions but most only use like the ID or something and I'm trying to POST and PUT in 3 things. Also I tried making some small changes to the data in the statement but they kept giving me different errors like bracket misplacement. Plz help this beginner U_U

My curl statement for posting in the database is.

```
curl -X POST -d '{"todo_ID":18,"UserID":6,"details":"Stop putting in the same things"}' -H "Content-Type:application/
json" http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

It says this error and I tried to make changes but still get the same error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.<
/p>
```

When using PUT my curl statement is

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type:applicat
ion/json" -d {"todo_ID":1,"UserID": 3,"details":"hi let it go"} http://127.0.0.1
:5000/update/1
```

I basically get the same error that I get for POST.

My code is.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify,json, request, abort
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('Config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class JsonModel(object): #Class for making objects JSON serializable
    def as_dict(self):
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

class User(db.Model, JsonModel): #Class which is a model for the User table in the database
    User_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    FirstName = db.Column(db.String(20))
    LastName = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def __init__(self,User_ID,FirstName, LastName):
        self.User_ID = User_ID
        self.FirstName = FirstName
        self.LastName = LastName

class Todo(db.Model, JsonModel):    #Class which is a model for the Todo table in the database
    todo_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.User_ID"))
    details = db.Column(db.String(30))

    def __init__(self,todo_ID, UserID,details):
        self.todo_ID = todo_ID
        self.UserID = UserID
        self.details = details

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])  #Uses POST method with same URL as GET method to add new information to Todo table.
def create_dev():
    dev = Todo(request.json["todo_ID"], request.json["UserID"], request.json["details"])
    db.session.add(dev)
    db.session.commit()
    return json.dumps([{'dev': dev}]), 201

@app.route('/update/<int:todo_ID>', methods = ['PUT'])
def update_todo(todo_ID):
    dev = Todo.query.get(todo_ID)
    dev.UserID = Todo(request.json["UserID"])
    dev.details = Todo(request.json["details"])
    db.session.update(dev)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify( { 'dev': dev})

@app.before_first_request #Creates everything before the first request.
def startup():
    db.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: What error is Flask reporting? Have you checked the logs or trying running your application with debug mode enabled?

Comment: Are you on windows?  It's likely your `curl` json string just isn't properly escaped.

Comment: yup im on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`400 Bad Requests` are usually seen when you're trying to access some data from the request that isn't there.

In your case it's probably failing when you first try to read `request.json["todo_ID"]` from your request because Flask has been unable to decode your json correctly.

Now, curl can be a bit of a pain to get working with json (check other SO questions on the subject).  The easiest way to test is to create an `example.json` text file with the contents:

```
{
    "todo_ID":18,
    "UserID":6,
    "details":"Stop putting in the same things"
}
```

Then adjust your curl command to use that file instead of handling the string itself, by running `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @example.json  http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

Your problem should disappear.

Comment: for some reason i get this error in pycharm the moment i use curl to post the data from the json file. it says unique constraint failed but when i check the database the new data is in there. Any chance you know why? also would it work if i use the put statement with data in json file too?

Comment: I assume this is now when you run the `update` route-- you make a mistake when you do ` dev.UserID = Todo(request.json["UserID"])` you should just be doing `dev.UserID = request.json["UserID"]` if you wish it to update.  You also don't need the `db.session.update(dev)`, when you commit, it'll save the changes to the `dev` object automatically.

Comment: this is for my POST. it works but says unique id constraint.